# Reverse cumsum for countdown functionality in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to ascertain how I can  create a column that "counts down" until the next occurrence of a value in another column with pandas that in essence performs the following functionality:

```
rowid  event   countdown
1      False   0 # resets countdown
2      True    2 # resets countdown
3      False   1
4      False   0
5      True    1 # resets countdown
6      False   0
7      True    1 # resets countdown
...
```

In which the event column defines whether or not an event in a column occurs (True) or not (False). And the countdown column identifies the number of subsequent rows/steps that have to occur until said event occurs. The following works for when one needs to "count up" to when an event occurs:

```
df.groupby(df.event.cumsum()).cumcount()
Out[46]: 
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    0
5    1
dtype: int64
```

However this effectively achieves the inverse of what I want to accomplish, is there a succinct method of achieving the former example, thanks!

Comment: So maybe is necessary add some `False, 0` row for  `7      True    1` ? Because else it should be `0`, because no another rows in sample data...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with `ascending=False`, there is last value `0` because sample data has only 7 rows and no another value after last:

```
df['new'] =  df.groupby(df.event.cumsum()).cumcount(ascending=False)
print (df)
   rowid  event  countdown  new
0      1  False          0    0
1      2   True          2    2
2      3  False          1    1
3      4  False          0    0
4      5   True          1    1
5      6  False          0    0
6      7   True          1    0
```

If logic is for last `True` is necessary set `1`:

```
df.iloc[[-1], df.columns.get_loc('new')] = int(df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('event')])
print (df)
   rowid  event  countdown  new
0      1  False          0    0
1      2   True          2    2
2      3  False          1    1
3      4  False          0    0
4      5   True          1    1
5      6  False          0    0
6      7   True          1    1
```